# RxJava Subscribe On Service Thread

Tags: android, android-service, rx-java, rx-android

I created a simple `IntentService` to upload a file and some data to a server. I want to be able to show a `Toast` when the upload has completed, but I need to be on the main thread in order to do so.

Since I am using RetroFit in combination with RxJava to handle the actual request, I thought I should use the `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` method to create the `Toast` on the main thread. The issue is that (because of the server) I may have to re-send the request, in which case I have to call the `postRequest()` method again.

Then this new request is now on the main thread. Therefore, in order to avoid that I used the `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` method, but this seems like a waste, considering the `Service` is already on its own thread.

Is there a way to specify that the `Observable` should `subscribeOn()` the `Service` thread? Or should I just subclass `Service` instead of `IntentService` and use the `io` thread?

```
private void postRequest(String title, LatLng location,
                         String description, MultipartBody.Part attachment) {
    mNetworkService.postRequest(title, location.latitude, location.longitude,
            description, attachment).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (response.status() == 1) {
                    ToastUtil.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Sent");
                    stopSelf();
                } else {
                    postRequest(title, location, description, attachment);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I miss something there, but why don't you filter the stream before subscribing with the "toaster"? I.e. filter the stream by `response.status()`. If successful, they can be passed to the toaster immediately, else they get send again.

This can happen before you return to the main thread, so you don't have to re-send it from there.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure using an `IntentService` is how I'd go about this myself but it's certainly possible to use its thread in Rx.

`IntentService` uses a Looper to do its work.  If you actually have a look inside `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` you can see that it's actually creating a scheduler from the main thread looper.  What you want to do is to create a scheduler from the IntentService Looper.

You can do this using:

```
Scheduler intentScheduler = AndroidSchedulers.from(Looper.myLooper());
```

Then you can do:

```
.observerOn(intentScheduler)
```

or

```
.subscribeOn(intentScheduler)
```

And it should use the thread of the IntentService